# does allegro uses X11 for creating display windows?

Tags: linux, x11, allegro

How are the windows created in linux when working on graphics using allegro library? does it uses X11 or its own primitive library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to draw anything on X11 server display, one have to use X11 protocol. There is just no reason to do it in any other way then using xlib one way or another.

http://alleg.sourceforge.net/stabledocs/en/build/unix.html

Short version: whenever X available, xlib is used. If none present, it will try SVGA directly on console.